# Prove the following inequality for any positive real numbers x,y,z

Tags: inequality

$x,y,z \in \Bbb R_+$ Prove that $xy + yz + zx \geq x\sqrt {yz} + y\sqrt{zx} + z\sqrt{xy}$

I couldn't find any useful application of AM-GM here. I also tried squaring both sides but it didn't help me either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xy+zx\geq 2x\sqrt{yz}$$
$$xy+yz\geq 2y\sqrt{xz}$$
$$yz+zx\geq 2z\sqrt{xy}$$ and now add them all and divide by $2$

Comment: As you wrote here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2753519/42969.

Answer (score 0):

Using $$A^2+B^2+C^2 \ge AB+ BC+ CA,$$ we get 
$$(xy+yz+zx)^2 \ge 3 xyz (x+y+z) \implies (xy+yz+zx \ge \sqrt{3} \sqrt{xyz} \sqrt{x+y+z} \ge\sqrt{xyz}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}) \ge x\sqrt{yz}+ y\sqrt{zx}+z\sqrt{xy}.$$

Lastly, we have used  RMS-AM inequality as $$\sqrt{\frac{A+B+C}{3}}\ge \frac{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}+\sqrt{C}}{3}$$ to get that